# Rails AJAX request 500 Internal Server Error details

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a form partial as follows:

**_internet_service_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @internet_service, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :start_date %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I render it in the new action of the controller, it returns a 500 internal server with no further explanation.

When I render it in the edit action of the controller, it renders correctly.

If I replace the partial with a text block with no rails tags in it, it renders correctly, so I know it's not a routing error.

**new.js.erb**

```
$("#result-content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'new')) %>");
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'internet_service_form' %>
```

**internet_service_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @internet_service = InternetService.new
end

def edit
  @internet_service = InternetService.find(params[:id])
end
```

These actions are being performed through AJAX, and the most useful logs I'm getting out of the development log are:

```
Started POST "/accounts/29/internet_services/new.js" for 10.12.68.100 at 2013-02-13 00:28:11 +1300
Processing by InternetServicesController#new as JS
  ... snip ...
  Rendered internet_services/_internet_service_form.html.erb (14.9ms)
  Rendered internet_services/_new.html.erb (24.3ms)
  Rendered internet_services/new.js.erb (32.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 231ms
```

Comment: Updated question with that code.

Comment: As stated though, when I change the content of the `internet_service_form` partial to something non-dynamic, it renders correctly when loaded, so I know it's getting to the point of rendering the correct file, it's something with the (very basic) simple_form that is throwing the error I can't narrow down.